# How can I extend a primitive's class and have typescript treat is as native primitive?

Tags: typescript

Is there anything I can do to the class below to make this second line valid?

```
export class NumberInput extends Number {}

const x = new NumberInput(1) + 1
```

Currently my only work-around is this:

```
const x = new NumberInput(1).valueOf() + 1
```

Or this:

```
const x = (new NumberInput(1) as number) + 1
```

But I'm interested in a one-shot way to make all instances of `NumberInput` behave as `number`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: If you want to lie to the compiler and tell it that `NumberInput` constructs primitive `number` values, you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na0GPw), but why would you want to do this?  Extending `Number` is probably not a good idea to begin with, and treating it like a primitive when it is not one is also not recommended.  Can you explain the use case?  It might be that there are better ways to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Piling on, but also would ask what's your purpose? There are good reasons for doing this, but there may be more appropriate solutions (such as branded types).